# Flutter SDK installation is not completed

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, flutter-dependencies

After updating flutter sdk it is showing  that flutter sdk installation is not completed . On the other hand i have saw the flutter official sdk installation page the sdk download is showing field .Please see the picture .

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpMgJ.png)

[Flutter SDk  installation is not completed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3FF5.png)

[Flutter SDK download page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sfeb.png)

Comment: Where is the picture?

Comment: Add the picture

Answer (score 1):

have you try re-installing flutter sdk?

Comment: I do not found the download zip folder .Its showing error . I here it is showing error you can check from flutter website

Comment: https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_v1.12.13+hotfix.5-stable.tar.xz

Comment: Link is working fined for me, that is the original link from the origanal page. Something is going wrong

Comment: If you want I can upload the flutter_linux_v1.12.13+hotfix.5-stable.tar.xz in mega

Comment: I have checked ..If i installed it then the dependency can not install